# Calculating length between 2 dates using Tkinter calendar

Tags: python, date, datetime, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter application where the user selects a date in a calendar and then presses a <kbd>button</kbd> and a `label` then displays the number of days between the current date and the date they have selected. I have figured out how to calculate the number of days between 2 set dates however when I introduced the calendar, it says the date `does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'` because the calendar sets the year of the date as 21 instead of 2021 e.g. `12/9/21`. Any solutions would be appreciated.

```
import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Date')
root.geometry("600x400")
from datetime import date
from time import strftime
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date
from datetime import datetime

def calculate():
    delta = b - a
    l1 = Label(root, text=delta.days)
    l1.pack()

#calendar
cal = Calendar(root, background="#99cbd8", disabledbackground="blue", bordercolor="#99cbd8", headersbackground="light blue", normalbackground="pink", foreground="blue", normalforeground='white', headersforeground='white', selectmode="day", year=2021, month=12, day=9)
cal.pack(pady=20)


plum = datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y") #getting the current date
pear = cal.get_date() #getting the date from the calendar

date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
a = datetime.strptime(plum, date_format)
b = datetime.strptime(pear, date_format)

button = Button(root, text="calc", command=calculate)
button.pack()
#delta = b - a
#print(delta.days)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `strptime` documentation will show that you can parse a date string with a 2-digit year using `%y` instead of `%Y`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, when I select a date on the calendar, the number of days until that date does not change and remains at 62, as it calculates until the default date of the calendar which I made the 9th December 2021. Even when I click a new date on the calendar it says 62.

Comment: The function `calculate` is using leftover global values of `a` and `b` each time. It needs to recompute them if you expect the result to change every time the calendar is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `date_pattern="m/d/y"` to `Calender(...)`:

```py
cal = Calendar(root, date_pattern="m/d/y", background="#99cbd8", disabledbackground="blue", bordercolor="#99cbd8", headersbackground="light blue", normalbackground="pink", foreground="blue", normalforeground='white', headersforeground='white', selectmode="day", year=2021, month=12, day=9)
```

Also you need to get the selected date inside `calculate()`:

```py
def calculate():
    pear = cal.get_date()
    b = datetime.strptime(pear, date_format)
    delta = b - a
    l1.config(text=delta.days) # update label

...
button = Button(root, text="calc", command=calculate)
button.pack()

# create the label
l1 = Label(root)
l1.pack()
...
```